# How do I Select a substring in Oracle SQL after a specific word in the string?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I am trying to extract everything in the following string after the word 'Hændelse'.

string:

```
Recordtype001[ efternavn = Nymark.] Adr2: 7020 Trondheim Hændelse A06: Udrejse er modtaget fra CPR-registeret.
```

I have tried to use REGEXP_SUBSTR - but it just returns the end of the string 't."'

I would like it to return

```
A06: Udrejse er modtaget fra CPR-registeret.
```

This is what I have tried:

```
WITH data AS
 (
    SELECT '"Recordtype001[ efternavn = Nymark.] Adr2: 7020 Trondheim Hændelse A06: Udrejse er modtaget fra CPR-registeret."' string 
    FROM dual
 )
 SELECT string,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, '[^Hændelse]+$') new_string
 FROM data;
```

Comment: Brackets make that a negated character class. Try something more like `Hændelse.*`

Comment: How about this: WITH data AS
 (
    SELECT '"Recordtype001[ efternavn = Nymark.] Adr2: 7020 Trondheim Hændelse A06: Udrejse er modtaget fra CPR-registeret."' string,
    'Hændelse' lookfor
    FROM dual
 )
 SELECT string,
        SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, lookfor||'.+'),LENGTH(lookfor)+2) new_string
 FROM data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not do what you want. You are defining a character class that must not contain characters from string '`Hændelse'`. Basically it is looking for a series of characters other than `'H'`, `'æ'`, `'n'`, `'d'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'s'`, `'e'`at the end of the string.

One option is `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(string, '^.*Hændelse\s*', '') new_string
```

Note that this would be more efficiently done with simple string functions (although a bit more convoluted):

```
ltrim(substr(string, instr(string, 'Hændelse') + length('Hændelse'))) new_string
```

Comment: I am new to this site - how do I rate the answer. It was perfect :-)